# Implementing an Iterator for a Set, tracking the current element

Tags: java, iterator, set

How do you code an `Iterator` for a `Set`? Given that the iterator does not have access to the underlying data storage mechanism, and can only use the `Set` methods, is it possible to do this?

Every implementation I've managed to find creates the `Iterator` as an anonymous class; however, I am trying to figure out if there is a clever way to iterate over a `Set` while only accessing the methods provided by `Set`.

So far, the best I've managed to come up with looks like this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class SetIterator<E> implements Iterator
{
    protected E[] arrayData;
    protected Set<E> set;
    protected int index;
    protected boolean canRemove;

    public SetIterator(Set<E> set)
    {
        this.set = set;
        this.arrayData = (E[]) set.toArray();
        this.index = -1;
        this.canRemove = false;
    }

    public E next()
    {
        if(this.hasNext())
        {
            this.canRemove = true;
            return this.arrayData[++this.index];
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("There is no next element");
        }
    }

    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        return this.index + 1 < this.arrayData.length;
    }

    public void remove()
    {
        if(this.canRemove)
        {
            this.set.remove(this.arrayData[index--]);
            this.arrayData = (E[]) this.set.toArray();
            this.canRemove = false;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot remove element before calling next");
        }
    }
}
```

But that feels quite kludgy.... Is there a better way?

Comment: I may have missed something here, but isn't your Iterator basically just a wrapper around an Iterable? Why do you need that, instead of just using the Set directly?

Comment: I am confused. Are you wondering why I need an iterator? What do you mean by use the set directly?

Comment: `Set` implements `Collection` which (in turn) implements `Iterable` with its mandatory  [`iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#iterator()) method.

Comment: Well, many implementations of `Set`s' `Iterator`s support removing elements. And even if your particular set doesn't, you could always copy it into a Set which does. So what are you trying to add to, say, `HashSet`'s iterator?

Comment: @AndyTurner I'm just trying to figure out how to write a `Set` iterator. I understand there are already working iterators for sets.

Comment: Is this a new class that you're implementing that you want to implement `Set`? If so, surely you know about the internal implementation, so you can do much better than the above. If not, you're reimplementing an iterator for something that already implements an iterator.

Comment: this is basically an iterator for an array.

Comment: @AndyTurner It is. And to make it more complicated, I'm implementing it in a different language (one with basically no available datastructures), and I'm using java as a sort of template. The language has no anonymous classes or inner classes, so I'm kinda limited to this strategy.

Answer (score 0):

I think your title doesn't leave much space for answers, but if I use the following as your actual question:

> How do you build an Iterator for a Set?

(and understand *build* as in *get an instance of*)

I think as **PM 77-1** pointed out in the comments: 
call the [`iterator()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#iterator%28%29) on it, which it has since [at least Java 1.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).

Keep in mind that it depends on the actual implementation of Set, wether the elements will always be iterated over in the same order.

Comment: Ahh, I think that is the source of confusion. Thank you for clearing that up for me. I don't want to get an instance of, I want to write one.

Comment: I read your comment above about another language (but I havn't enough reputation to answer the comments above), why are you using "java as a template" and not telling which language you are talking about?

But anyhow: I assume you can not touch the set or its internal structure? Then I think your solution is fine. 
(And I think no one will be able to provide a better one if you keep talking about Java ;) )

Comment: The language is PHP, which won't have anonymous classes until [7.0](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/anonymous_classes). It has to be [PSR](http://www.php-fig.org/) compliant. I am also building the `Set`, but due to the above constraints, that doesn't help me very much.

Comment: Sorry, but still not understanding the problem. Why would you need to have anonymous class to do this. Are you talking about PHP 5? From a short look at the docs, implementing a set and implementing [Iterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) shouldn't be to diffucult. e.g. using the keys of an array to create a Set and [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to provide the iterator. I think for more details you could open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

if we look in AbstractCollection we will see that toArray actually calls the iterator() (abstract method) to produce the array which you will use,  so your method still depends on the specific iterator, so you are essentially decorating the iterator.

```
    public Object[] toArray() {
    // Estimate size of array; be prepared to see more or fewer elements
    Object[] r = new Object[size()];
    Iterator<E> it = iterator();
    for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
        if (! it.hasNext()) // fewer elements than expected
            return Arrays.copyOf(r, i);
        r[i] = it.next();
    }
    return it.hasNext() ? finishToArray(r, it) : r;
}
```

Still not sure what you are trying to accomplish, the underlying datastructure of the set will have different (and specific) ways to efficently iterate the data, any generic solution would sacrafice performance,  using the iterable interface should be generic enough.